# How to use row_number() in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, row-number

I want to update row data where the `row_number` of the column (`p_id`) is 1.. but this syntax is providing error:

```
update app1 
set p_id = 1 
where Row_Number() = 1 over(p_id)
```

Comment: Which row(s) are you trying to update? Not clear to me from the code you have supplied?

Comment: @user, you need to explain in more detail what is the logic of the update you are trying to perform..

Comment: @martin and gaby---my logic is that if checkbox is checked then on button click i want to update the column of table app1 depending upon which checkbox was checked(in side gridview)

Comment: @user635545 - You should just pass the primary key into the `where` clause of the `update` statement for this. Not use `row_number` at all. This is the most efficient way and also the correct way. Are you assuming (for example) that the 7th row in the grid will always be the 7th row in the table as ordered by `p_id`?  What if a concurrent transaction has deleted a row? You could end up updating the wrong one.

Comment: @martin lets say p_no is primary key and i use following code but there is no effect on table 'update app1 set p_no=1 where p_id=p_no'

Comment: the above where clause don't make any sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This will update only the first employee of that age. May be used as a lottery type logic**

```
create table emp(name varchar(3),Age int, Salary int, IncentiveFlag bit)

insert into emp values('aaa',23,90000,0);
insert into emp values('bbb',22,50000,0);
insert into emp values('ccc',63,60000,0);
insert into emp values('ddd',53,50000,0);
insert into emp values('eee',23,80000,0);
insert into emp values('fff',53,50000,0);
insert into emp values('ggg',53,50000,0);

update A
set IncentiveFlag=1
from 
(
        Select row_number() over (partition by Age order by age ) AS SrNo,* from emp
)A
where A.SrNo=1
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @subhash--thank you very much sir...u have used UPDATE A...A indicate view?

Answer (score 7):

You can't use `ROW_NUMBER()` directly - you need to e.g. use a CTE (Common Table Expression) for that:

```
;WITH DataToUpdate AS
(
    SELECT
       SomeID,
       p_id,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY .......) AS 'RowNum'
    FROM
       dbo.app1
)
UPDATE DataToUpdate
SET p_id = 1
WHERE 
   RowNum = 1
```

In order to use the `ROW_NUMBER` function, you also need at least an `ORDER BY` clause to define an order by which the rows are ordered.

From your question, it's not very clear what criteria (column) you want to order by to determine your `ROW_NUMBER()`, and it's also not clear what kind of column there is to uniquely identify a row (so that the `UPDATE` can be applied)

Comment: @andriy M: well a subselect isn't all that different from a CTE - but without any form of subselect or CTE, you cannot directly use a row_number() - right?? You definitely can't use it the way the OP tried to use it - agreed?

Comment: I'm sorry, I had to delete my comment because I missed the 'update' bit of the original post. The direct use is out of question in that case.

Comment: By the way, I think it is possible to `UPDATE cte` if it references only one table.

Comment: The OP's syntax is just wrong. But did you actually try using `ROW_NUMBER()` in the WHERE clause? I didn't and I can't check it at the moment.

Comment: @Andriy M: I believe you're right on this second point - updated my answer accordingly! Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Andriy M: yes - I tried - it gives error: `Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.`

Comment: @Andriy M: and the trouble is: if you use a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS "RN"` in your SELECT, you cannot reference that "RN" column alias in the WHERE clause - you need at least a subselect or a CTE...

Comment: Re: Error message – That's a shame. Still I suspected as much, and it's great to have it confirmed, thanks.

Comment: Sometimes you only need to return the ranking with the rest of the data, e.g. in a view, or to the client, even if those are rare use cases probably.

Answer (score 0):

TO Delete duplicates                                                                 ;WITH CTE(Name,Address1,Phone,RN)
AS
(
SELECT Name,Address1,Phone,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name) AS RN
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1

Comment: Duplicate records in a table